# Adding @angular/pwa to an existing project

Tags: angular

I've added `@angular/pwa` to an existing project.

I have a flag `serviceWorker: true` in `angular.json` and i have registered the service worker with a new file `sw-register.js`.

The `sw-register.js` file:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js', {
    scope: '/',
}).then((registration) => {
    console.log("Service worker OK!")
});
```

}

I've also added `<script src="/sw-register.js"></script>` and `<link href="manifest.json">` to my `index.html` file.

When i run the app localy in production mode everything is fine.
But when I push it on a server I recive an error in dev tools:
`Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.`

Can somebody help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use `@angular/cli`?

Comment: Yes, i use `@angular/cli v6.0.5`

Comment: Ok, so let me explain, the `@angular/pwa` will set up your app with a service worker without any required step. Though the service worker will be only visible when you build your app with `ng build --prod`

Comment: It didn't set up the service worker automaticly. It doesn't work without registering the service worker.

Comment: Remove your current pwa related code, and start over with this https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#adding-a-service-worker-to-your-project